# How can I get rid of the whitespace and put my image at the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm unsure how to remove the whitespace for the top div. I want the image in the page to start at the top and go under the header div so that the header div overlaps but it just won't do that and I'm unsure on how to do it.

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: ;
  background-color: ;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}

li {
  display: inline;
  color: ;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #323232;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  color: #323232;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.picture {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"><br>
  <ul>
    <li> <a class="atest" href="/">item 5</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="atest " href="/">item 3</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="atest " href="Blog">item 3</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="atest " href="Gallery">item 2</a> </li>
    <li> <a class="atest " href="Schtuff">item 1</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
</div>

<img class="picture" src="https://4get.ca/proxy?i=https%3A%2F%2Fi1.wp.com%2Fhandluggageonly.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F01%2FHand-Luggage-Only-5-4.jpg%3Ffit%3D1600%252C904%26ssl%3D1" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="" height="">
<div class="test">
  <h1>testtrtertert</h1>
  <p>tyer te45rt herter tertkgh eruithetrther ther</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin, padding, flexbox properties, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "position:fixed;" for "header" class, it would be help for it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: Arial;
      color: ;
      background-color: ;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline;
      color: ;
    }
    
    a,
    a:hover,
    a:focus,
    a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .header {
      background-color: green;
      color: #323232;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0.3;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .picture {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      position: inherit;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header"><br>

    <ul>
      <li> <a class="atest" href="/">item 5</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="atest " href="/">item 3</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="atest " href="Blog">item 3</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="atest " href="Gallery">item 2</a> </li>
      <li> <a class="atest " href="Schtuff">item 1</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
  </div>

  <img class="picture" src="https://4get.ca/proxy?i=https%3A%2F%2Fi1.wp.com%2Fhandluggageonly.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F01%2FHand-Luggage-Only-5-4.jpg%3Ffit%3D1600%252C904%26ssl%3D1" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="" height="">

  <div class="test">
    <h1>testtrtertert</h1>
    <p>tyer te45rt herter tertkgh eruithetrther ther</p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ok, like no joke, i tried that but you clearly must have used superior knowledge to rectify my mistake! cheers!